# Urllib displays syntax error when collecting url from user

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib

I'm working on a simple web scraping program in Python that collects the names of links in a web document using urllib and BeautifulSoup.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Not link used in project. Just a sample URL
html = urllib.urlopen('http://stackoverflow.com/index.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
count = int(input("Enter Count: "))
position = int(input("Enter Position: "))
tags = soup("a")
```

When I type the url as a plain string into my code as shown in the above (at "urllib.urlopen"), everything works perfectly.

But in this code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = str(input("Enter URL: "))
html = urllib.urlopen(link).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
count = int(input("Enter Count: "))
position = int(input("Enter Position: "))
tags = soup("a")
```

When I type in my input, I get a syntax error due to the colon in the URL:

```
link = str(input("Enter URL: "))
File "<string>", line 1
http:stackoverflow.com
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have no idea why the colon in the URL is causing a syntax error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You appear to be running this Python 3 code in a Python 2 interpreter. `input` in Python 2 tries to literally evaluate the input the user supplies. Change what interpreter you're using to fix this.

Comment: I only have python 3 installed and my interpreter is also in python 3. That was the first thing I checked before I asked this question.

Comment: Or, if you must use Python 2, use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.

Comment: I would quadruple check that. I don't think this error is possible in Python 3.

Comment: I'll do just so. Thanks!

Comment: That error is absolutely from Python 2.